# Generating a range of numbers using code igniter in a for loop and saving in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, active-directory, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Iam trying to generate random numbers in codeigniter using a for loop. Generated numbers should be saved in database. In my code only one row is added in database. below is my code.

**View**

```
  <form action="<?php echo site_url('/Gen/gen_num'); ?>" method="post">
  <select name="country_code_id" class="form-control show-tick" required>
   <option value="">263</option>
    </select>
    <select name="mobile_operator_prefix_id" class="form-control show-tick" required>
     <option value="0">772</option>
     <option value="1">774</option>
     <option value="2"> 774</option>
    </select>
   <input type="hidden" name="mobile_number" placeholder="Mobile Number">                                                            
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" placeholder="How many numbers ?" required>
  <button class="btn btn-block bg-pink waves-effect" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
   </form>
```

**Contoller**

```
$quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
for ($x=0; $x<$quantity; $x++) {   
$mobile_number = rand(10000, 99999);
$data = array(
           'mobile_operator_prefix_id' => $this->input->post('mobile_operator_prefix_id'),
           'country_code_id' => $this->input->post('country_code_id'),
            'mobile_number' => $mobile_number,
 );
$this->Gen_model->save_number($data);  
}
```

**Model**

```
function save_number($data){
                        $this->db->insert('mobile_numbers', $data);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks fine - you just have to remove your semicolon after your for loop - try this instead

```
$quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
for ($x=0; $x<$quantity; $x++)
{   
    $mobile_number = rand(10000, 99999);
    $data = array(
        'mobile_operator_prefix_id' => $this->input->post('mobile_operator_prefix_id'),
        'country_code_id' => $this->input->post('country_code_id'),
        'mobile_number' => $mobile_number,
    );
    $this->Gen_model->save_number($data);  
}
```

> For better understanding you can take a look at [this PHP Sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12cabf7e59391cf0e760e5732c5313de714b5a18)

Comment: Owwwhh..that was the issue. I removed the semicolon and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much